# How to use navigation at app from imported child component (navigation component)?

Tags: react-native

**I am trying to use navigation at app screen where navigation imported in app screen. but it shows error. can not read property navigate is undefined.**

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Navigation from './App/Components/Navigation';
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';
export default class App extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    .........
  }  
   ..........
  onOpened(openResult) {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Screen2');
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Navigation/>
      );
  }  
}
```

Navigation.js - Here is navigation component which is imported at App.js but its shows an error - Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
How can i solve this problem.

Thanks Advance..............

Answer (score -1):

Has I understood you are trying to navigate one screen to another screen right.

You can try with ( react-native-navigation-stack )
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation

```
npm install --save react-navigation-stack
```

Create Navigation.js

```
 import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import Login from './Login'
 import SignUp from './SignUp'
 var AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        }
      },
    SignUp: {
            screen: SignUp,
            navigationOptions: {
              header: null
            }
          },
    },
    {
       initialRouteName: 'Login',
     })
    export default NavigateStack = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

In App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation' 
export default class App extends Component { 
        render()
        {
                return ( <Navigation /> );
        }
 }
```

In login.js

```
signup = () =>
{ 
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp') 
}
```

Comment: @Balaji i am already used react native navigation. you can see navigation component imported at app js. but when i navigate from app js then its show this message. otherwise my navigation work fine.

Comment: Oohhoo ok man -Zilon Jakir, It's look like props have not set navigate

Comment: @balaji, i want to redirect to screen2 from push notification. when i click. and the push notification code at app JSD.

Comment: Use onpress() with sigup function in button on ur 1st screen

Comment: @balaji i saw your code. you are right. but i want to use this.props.navigation.navigate at app.js page.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, add app.js in navigation.js and try similar process to that, but I'm not sure in this.

Comment: @balaji is it possible to redirect to another page without stack navigation?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I have not seen anything like that without navigation stack